# Event handlers making multiple server calls in google map api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing weird issue in google map events. I am  attaching centre _changed event for panning and dragend event for the map below, but the whenever i drag map both dragand and center_changes events are getting called multiple times because which there multiple server calls. so is there any specific events or please let me know how to hanldes these events. 
In bing map there are dedicated events like onstartpan,onendpan which works perfectly but in gmap is the issue. 
I tried for TimeOut function, but nothing works. 
There should be just one server call for when panned in any diredction or dragging the map,

```
//// for panning
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        // setTimeout(function () {
        if (eventTriggered != "zoom" && !Inprogress) {
            Inprogress = true;
            GMapvApiV3.LoadData(GMapvApiV3.GetMapBoundaries());
            Inprogress = false;
        }
        //}, 1000);
    });
});


google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    //setTimeout(function () {
    if (!Inprogress) {
        Inprogress = true;
        alert('ok');
        GMapvApiV3.LoadData(GMapvApiV3.GetMapBoundaries());
        Inprogress = false;
    }
    //}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Check out the event 'bounds_changed'.  That reacts to any corner of the map being different; so that is an event on zoom, pan and resize

Comment: yep.. even tried with bounds_cahnged but thats also making multiple server calls....